# Django doesn't show images after adding multiple environments

Tags: django

I'm trying to add local and production environments to my Django project. So instead of one **settings.py** file, I created a **settings directory** and in that directory, added 3 settings files: **base.py**, **local.py**, and **pro.py**

settings (directory)

- base.py (the new name for settings.py)
- local.py (inherits from base.py with some parameter overrides)
- pro.py (inherits from base.py with some parameter overrides)

In the **base.py** file, I updated the **BASE_DIR** parameter to point to the parent folder of the current file.

previous BASE_DIR:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

new BASE_DIR:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(
                            os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir))))
```

I didn't change static and media root parameters (in base.py):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

However, after the change, my images don't show up anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir)` will result in something like `/path/to/myproject/settings/base.py/..`.

If you've moved the `base.py` a level deeper (than the original `settings.py`), you can just add another `os.path.dirname`, E.g.

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```